# How can I test commits on Kafka MockConsumer?

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-kafka

When I started to investigate more into Unit testing my Kafka consuming methods, I could not believe just how painfully hard testing with a MockConsumer could be.

I have a piece of code that uses (a.k.a. try with resources) a `Consumer<K,V>`.

In a unit test, I provide a `MockConsumer<K,V>` instance and simulate records. (even that was *much* harder than I anticipated...)

Once the test has run, I need to assert certain things - e.g. did my code commit the right messages?

I tried it all - but apparently *all* calls to *any* methods hinting at this give me an Exception
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: This consumer has already been closed.`

Yes - of course - my resource has been closed after my method. Because I am doing it the clean way to use a resource, a.k.a. automatically closing it after using it. But how on earth am I to check what has been committed after the fact? Isn't that what a Mock is all about?

Please enlighten me...

For those of you, who have never heard about MockConsumer -> https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/MockConsumer.html

Comment: What is `MockConsumer`? It comes from some library? Which one?

Comment: Is this a joke...? ;-) It comes with Apache Kafka and is supposed to be *the* way to mock a consumer.

Comment: If you want to check if the commit was called you can mock the Consumer<K,V> class and verify the call instead of using the MockConsumer<K,V> for that particular test or in general.